# Execute stored procedure with multiple named parameter with PDO_DBLIB & sql server database

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

I am trying to update the data stored in my SQL database with PDO_DBLIB driver and php. To update the data I just have to pass few named parameter to stored procedure and it gets done but when I try with below code it gives me no error but nothing gets updated in the database. I am recording statement executiong in json response to track.
Here is my code :

```
$conn = new PDO("dblib:$dsn","$uname", "$pwd");

$sth = $conn->prepare("EXECUTE SP_Web_Contact_Update :Person_ID, :ContactType_Code_ID, :Contact_Info, :Contact_ClassID"); 

$sth->bindValue(':Person_ID', $syntonicID, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sth->bindValue(':ContactType_Code_ID', $codeid, PDO::PARAM_STR );
$sth->bindValue(':Contact_Info', $contactinfo, PDO::PARAM_STR );

$truefalse = $sth->execute();
echo json_encode($trufalse);
```

above code always prints `true` which gives me no information to troubleshoot further. can you guyz assist me on this ?

Comment: Without further information or the code of the stored procedure, this would be difficult to help with. I went through a similar issue and my suggestion is to use SQL Profiler to capture the call to the database and then run it manually in SQL Management Studio to observer the response. I've had the manual run work where it failed coming from PHP which then led me down other paths. Let me know if it works when run manually or not and we can take it from there. (The issue I was having was there was both a trigger and constraint on the table which didn't like the external call)

Answer (score 0):

If your `$sth->execute()` call returns `true`, then your stored procedure is executed without errors. 
You have four placeholders, but only three `bindValue()` calls, which probably means, that your stored procedure is executed with default value for the forth parameter.
This is one possible reason for the missing updates in your database.

As an option, you may try to get the count of rows affected by the `UPDATE` statement in your stored procedure with [PDOStatement::rowCount()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php)

You may also consider to include some exception handling. Try with next basic approach (using your code):

```
<?php
...

# PDO Connection
try {
    $conn = new PDO("dblib:$dsn","$uname", "$pwd");
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch( PDOException $e ) {
    die( "Error connecting to SQL Server".$e->getMessage());
}

# Statement
try {
    $result = 0;
    $sth = $conn->prepare("EXECUTE :Result = SP_Web_Contact_Update :Person_ID, :ContactType_Code_ID, :Contact_Info, :Contact_ClassID");
    $sth->bindParam(':Result', $result, PDO::PARAM_INT | PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT, PDO::SQLSRV_PARAM_OUT_DEFAULT_SIZE); 
    $sth->bindParam(':Person_ID', $syntonicID, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $sth->bindParam(':ContactType_Code_ID', $codeid, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $sth->bindParam(':Contact_Info', $contactinfo, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    #$sth->bindParam(':Contact_ClassID', $??????, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $truefalse = $sth->execute();
    $rowcount = $sth->rowCount();
    echo json_encode($result); 
    echo json_encode($trufalse);
    echo json_encode($rowcount);
} catch( PDOException $e ) {
    die("Error executing query: ".$e->getMessage() );
}

...

# 
$sth = null;
$conn = null;
?>
```

Comment: Okay I missed to write that fourth parameter bindvalue here, but I tried above and it still gives me rowcount = -1

Comment: @VJAmbaliya In this case, the code of the stored procedure will be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: that means above syntaxes are correct its just stored procedure code that's organized differently! I mean taking parameter values differently! sadly I don't have access to stored procedure code!

Comment: @VJAmbaliya Yes, I think so. I usually use `bindParam()` (you may try this), but `bindValue()` will work because you don't change the PHP variables values. Thanks.

Comment: Yep, Tried with `bindParam()` as well with `execute(array)` nothing worked

Comment: I forget to mention that I am executing all this in GET API request, so that once executed I get a response true or false!

Comment: @VJAmbaliya I've updated the answer with one additional check. You may try to get the result code from execution of your stored procedure. `$truefalse` variable returns the result from statement execution, but you need to check what your procedure returns.

Comment: Okay thanks I'll give it a try now! and get back to you!

Comment: Its giving me ```0 false 0``` now